# Зачёркнутые ссылки не работают

Tags: дефект, поддержка, markdown

При вот такой разметке

```
<s>https://ru.stackoverflow.com/</s>
```

зачёркнутая ссылка показывается в превью сообщения, но после сохранения исчезает и остайтся только текст:

<s>https://ru.stackoverflow.com/</s>

И скриншот [с основного сайта](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1143270/178988):

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Почему не на MSE?

Comment: [meta-tag:статус-так-задумано]

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, неа, всё равно баг, потому что в превью и при отправке работает по-разному, а должно одинаково.

Comment: вернул метки обратно

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<s>[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)</s>
```

=>

> <s>https://ru.stackoverflow.com/</s>

Вообще это так задумано: ссылка становится ссылкой, только если она отдельно от Mаrkdown  или HTML, а если она внутри тега/-ов, то уже нет. Да и вaще зачем зачеркнутую ссылку оставлять ссылкой? Ведь она уже не работает!

---

[статус-так-задумано](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be)

Comment: Проставил статус.

Comment: @AK OK ;) (where is EK, IK, UK?)